# How to retrieve data from multiple Stata files?

Tags: stata, multiple-databases

I have 53 Stata `.dta` files each of them is 150 - 200 Mb and contain identical set of variables, but for different years. It is not useful to combine or merge them due to their size .

I need to retrieve some averaged values (percentages etc.) Therefore, I want to create a new Stata file `New.dta` and write a `.do` file that would run on that new Stata file in the following way: ***it should open each of those 53 Stata files, make certain calulations, and store the results in the new Stata file, `New.dta.`***

I am not sure how i can keep two Stata file open simultaneuosly, and how can i store the calculated values?

When I open a second .dta file, how can i make the first one still be open? How can i store the calculated values in the global variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What springs to mind here is the use of `postfile`.

Here is a simple example. First, I set up an example of several datasets. You already have this.

```
clear

forval i = 1/10 {
    set obs 100
    gen foo = `i' * runiform()
    save test`i'
    clear
}
```

Now I set up `postfile`. I need to set up a handle, what variables will be used, and what file will be used. Although I am using a numeric variable to hold file identifiers, it will perhaps be more typical to use a string variable. Also, looping over filenames may be a bit more challenging than this. `fs` from SSC is a convenience command that helps put a set of filenames into a local macro; its use is not illustrated here.

```
postfile mypost what mean using alltest.dta

forval i = 1/10 {
    use test`i', clear
    su foo, meanonly
    post mypost (`i')  (`r(mean)')
}
```

Now flush results

```
postclose mypost
```

and see what we have.

```
u alltest

list 

     +-----------------+
     | what       mean |
     |-----------------|
  1. |    1   .5110765 |
  2. |    2   1.016858 |
  3. |    3   1.425967 |
  4. |    4   2.144528 |
  5. |    5   2.438035 |
     |-----------------|
  6. |    6   3.030457 |
  7. |    7   3.356905 |
  8. |    8   4.449655 |
  9. |    9   4.381101 |
 10. |   10   5.017308 |
     +-----------------+
```

I didn't use any global macros (not global variables) here; you should not need to.

Comment: thanks a lot...i tried it...but still get `post mypost not found`. i tried creating `mypost.dta`...still the same error. is `mypost.dta` the target file?

Comment: You are going to have to post what code you tried. Otherwise I can only suggest that you have a syntax error.

Comment: I have added the code that i tried in my question above...the layout is not good in the comment section...

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach is to loop over files and use `collapse` to "condense" these files to the relevant means, and than `append` these condensed files. Here is an adaptation of Nick's example:

```
// create the example datasets
clear

forval i = 1/10 {
    set obs 100
    gen foo = `i' * runiform()
    gen year = `i'
    save test`i', replace
    clear
}

// use collapse and append
// to create the dataset you want
use test1, clear
collapse (mean) year foo 
save means, replace
forvalues i = 2/10 {
    use test`i', clear
    collapse (mean) year foo 
    append using means
    save means, replace
}

// admire the result
list
```

Comment: This is a good method and likely to be easier to understand. As Maarten would happily underline, it is strictly limited to what `collapse` can do. But if you like this route, be aware also of `contract`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if your data sets are not named sequentially like `test1.dta`, `test2.dta`, ..., `test53.dta`, but rather like `results-alaska.dta`, `result_in_alabama.dta`, ..., `"wyoming data.dta"` (note the space and hence the quotes), you would have to organize the cycle over these files somewhat differently:

```
local allfiles : dir . files "*.dta"
foreach f of local allfiles {
   use `"`f'"', clear
   * all other code from Maarten's or Nick's approach
}
```

This is a more advanced of local macros, see [help extended macro functions](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?extended_fcn). Note also that Stata will produce a list that will look like `"results-alaska.dta" "result_in_alabama.dta" "wyoming data.dta"` with quotes around file names, so when you invoke `use`, you will have to enclose the file name into [compound quotes](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?quotes).