# How to store a mean value in a local macro and then save it in another file?

Tags: stata, local-variables, stata-macros

I have a Stata file `file1.dta` and one of the variables is `income`. I need to calculate `average_income`, assign it to a local macro, and store in a different Stata file, `New.dta`.

I have tried the following in a `do` file:

```
#delimit;
clear;
set mem 700m;

use file1.dta;
local average_income = mean income; 

use New.dta;
gen avincome = average_income;
```

However, it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be the following:

```
#delimit;
clear;
set mem 700m;

use file1.dta;
quietly: summarize income;
local average_income = r(mean); 

use New.dta;
gen avincome = `average_income';
```

Comment: Hi @stately_treasures thank you for reply. I tried and have the following error: . `gen avincome = average_income;
average_income not found`

Comment: You need `\`average_income'` in the last line. That is a local macro and needs to be referred to as such. Otherwise Stata will look for a variable or scalar with that name, and will not find it.

Comment: The bigger deal is the poster's other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781571/how-to-retrieve-data-from-multiple-stata-files of how to do this for _several_ files.

Answer (score 2):

This overlaps with your other post, namely [How to retrieve data from multiple Stata files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781571/how-to-retrieve-data-from-multiple-stata-files). You don't say why you think

```
use file1.dta;
local average_income = mean income;
```

will work, but the second line is just fantasy syntax. There are various ways to calculate the mean of a variable, the most common being to use `summarize` and pick up the mean from `r(mean)`.

You should probably delete this question: it serves no long-term purpose.