# How to work around Stata's restriction on using `by` option with `count` command?

Tags: sorting, count, stata

I need to calculate the percentage of high school education by states. But Stata function `count` does not allow `by` option. So far I have the following:

```
count
local totalPopulation = r(N )

count if schenr==0
local eduBelowHighSchool = r(N)
local _eduBelowHighSchool=`eduBelowHighSchool'/`totalPopulation'

count if schenr==1
local eduHighSchool = r(N )
local _eduHighSchool=`eduHighSchool'/`totalPopulation'

count if schenr==2
local eduCollege = r(N )
local _eduCollege=`eduCollege'/`totalPopulation'

gen eduBelowHighSchool =`_eduBelowHighSchool'
gen eduHighSchool =`_eduHighSchool'
gen eduCollege =`_eduCollege'
```

**// How can I calculate individual values for each state? I cannot use `count, by (state)`, can I?** The above code produces the following table:

[image]

Is there any other way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`count` is a Stata command, not a function. In Stata, "function" is not another term for "command"; rather, commands and functions are separate.

In your example, `schenr` is evidently 1 when high school and 0 when not. It follows that the percent you want is just the mean of `schenr` (multiplied by 100).

If you want a new variable,

```
egen pc_highschool = mean(100 * schenr), by(state)
```

will put the same percent in every observation to which it applies. To get a listing of each state just once,

```
egen tag = tag(state)
l state pc_highschool if tag
```

is one way to do it.

But you can get tables using `tabulate`, `table`, `tabstat` without necessarily creating a new variable. Consider this reproducible example:

```
. sysuse auto 

. tabulate rep78, su(foreign) nost

        Repair |   Summary of Car type
   Record 1978 |        Mean       Freq.
   ------------+------------------------
             1 |           0           2
             2 |           0           8
             3 |          .1          30
             4 |          .5          18
             5 |   .81818182          11
   ------------+------------------------
         Total |   .30434783          69

. gen foreign2 = 100 * foreign

. tabulate rep78, su(foreign2) nost

        Repair |   Summary of foreign2
   Record 1978 |        Mean       Freq.
   ------------+------------------------
             1 |           0           2
             2 |           0           8
             3 |          10          30
             4 |          50          18
             5 |   81.818182          11
   ------------+------------------------
         Total |   30.434783          69
```

If you want a new dataset, use `contract`. (Compare the answer to your very recent question [How to retrieve data from multiple Stata files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781571/how-to-retrieve-data-from-multiple-stata-files) .)

Comment: many thanks for your constant help. Actually, the `schenr` variable can take values 0,1,2 (i specified 0 and 1 to simplify the question). So, can i still use `egen...by(state)` in this case? i think `mean` is not going to work, so is there any other command/function i could use instead of `count`?

Comment: Quite so on your data. The `egen` approach can easily be adapted to that. `egen pc_highschool = mean(100 * (schenr == 1)), by(state)` gives the percent of 1s, and so on. See also http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-percent-summary-variables/ and http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/  `contract` does do this simply.

Comment: If you are unsure whether something is a command or a function, type in Stata `help function` which gives you more information on what functions are in Stata and why you cannot use the terms "command" and "function" interchangeably in Stata.